# Automate FTP transfer between servers

Tags: bash, ftp, sh, cpanel, plesk

I apparently need to support some legacy hardware that ftp's into a shared server IP that is hardcoded into their software.

I'm just looking for something simple and straight forward that grabs the all files from the legacy server and copies them to a current server. Ideally it only does this when the time stamp on the legacy server is newer then the what is on the current server, at set intervals of probably 5 minutes or so.

I suppose I could schedule a cronjob with ftp and "mget *" the files inside of directories of the legacy windows server. But that pulls all of the files every five minutes and that's not necessary.

What functionality I'm actually looking for would be something like "mnewer *" if it existed, or I suppose I may have to write a script that achieves this, however I feel like this is something basic and there should be an easier way to achieve this and I'm just not finding it.

Comment: Hello, your question seems too broad. Please see the _[help/on-topic]_.

Comment: Can you use `rsync` instead?

Comment: can't use rsync. The legacy server is a shared godaddy plesk. Thus ssh to it is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Not only the *ftp* client supports the FTP protocol, also *curl* and *wget* can be used for this purpose.
By the way, *wget* has a nice mirroring feature built-in:

```
wget --quiet --mirror ftp://someusername:somepassword@legacyserver
```

will recursively retrieve the files/folders from your server.
When you watch this in Wireshark you'll see that only the *newer* files are retrieved, so you won't repeatedly retrieve the same file versions.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the functionality I was looking for, much better then an nlist and ftp newer script.